# Simple Example: Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline

Tags: powershell, filtering, where-clause

Can explain why philosophically this doesn't work? 
Just as a learning example, I wanted to see the properties of the get-service cmdlet, without the events or methods.

```
PS C:\Users\Neal> get-service | get-member |  {$_.name -eq "Property"}
```

Result:

```
At line:1 char:29
+ get-service | get-member |  {$_.name -eq "Property"}
+                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpressionsMustBeFirstInPipeline
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`{$_.name -eq "Property"}` is just a [scriptblock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574146/what-exactly-is-a-powershell-scriptblock).  If you want to use [`Where-Object`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177028.aspx) to filter the results of `get-member`, you need to type `Where-Object`:

```
PS C:\Users\Neal> get-service | get-member | Where-Object {$_.name -eq "Property"}
```

or you can use `where`, which is an alias for `Where-Object`:

```
PS C:\Users\Neal> get-service | get-member | where {$_.name -eq "Property"}
```

There is even a special character `?` which refers to `Where-Object`:

```
PS C:\Users\Neal> get-service | get-member | ? {$_.name -eq "Property"}
```

All three examples given above do the same thing.  Choosing between them is simply a matter of style.

Comment: Thanks, so sometimes, for example, on the first expression only, you can actually leave off the word "where"

Comment: or just `Get-Member -MemberType Properties` without piping to Where

Comment: That's much better!  (And in the example I posted, I meant to have $_.MemberType not $_.Name).